# Abstract class logic problems

Tags: java

I am trying to make one program and here is my problem:

I have interface 'Engine'.

`EngineFactory.createEngine(request)`

In the factory I have:

```
if(request instanceof TypeA){ return new TypeAAA(request);}
if(request instanceof TypeB){ return new TypeBBB(request);}
```

Sadly in the constructors when I try to do:

```
(TypeA) requestArg
```

It is saying - undefined constructor. Can I do that without the obvious casting of (TypeAAA)TypeA requestArg)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to cast it to `TypeA` and not `TypeAAA` if it's instanceof `TypeA`?

Anyway, yes, you still have to cast it yourself even though you checked if it was an `instanceof` the class just prior. In Kotlin the compiler would be smart enough to figure it out but with Java you still have to do the cast.

Comment: yep thanks for the answer, edited, because of the typo.

Comment: is there a more elegant way as this was the thing I was trying to avoid? I dont know why but nowadays instanceof ...cast, is a hated structure :)

Comment: It depends on what you want your Engine to do. They might inherit from the same super class and have very similar behaviour in which case you can simply override the methods for the particular subclass and the classes using the object don't even have to know exactly what type of class it is, just that it inherits from Engine.

Think of how the interfaces in the Java collections are implemented for example, if you use a List you don't have to know if it's actually a ListArray or a Vector, simply that it adheres to the contract of a List.